# Why is my square grid rendering as a rectangle?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and JavaScript, but I've been trying to build a simple "pairs" game with images. Match two images and get points. I have most of what I want, but the grid renders 5x20 rather than the 10x10 I'm specifying in the code.

```js
const gridContainer = document.getElementById('grid-container');
const scoreElement = document.getElementById('score');

const numberOfPairs = 50;
const gridSize = 10 * 10;
let gridItems = [];
let score = 0;
let firstSelected = null;

// Generate the image pairs
function createImagePairs() {
  const pairs = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfPairs; i++) {
    pairs.push(`img${i}a`);
    pairs.push(`img${i}b`);
  }
  return pairs;
}

// Shuffle the image pairs array
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

// Create the grid
function createGrid() {
  const imagePairs = createImagePairs();
  const shuffledPairs = shuffle(imagePairs);

  for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    const gridItem = document.createElement('div');
    gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
    gridItem.dataset.pairId = shuffledPairs[i].substring(0, shuffledPairs[i].length - 1);

    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = `images/${shuffledPairs[i]}.jpg`;
    gridItem.appendChild(image);

    gridItem.addEventListener('click', handleItemClick);

    gridItems.push(gridItem);
    gridContainer.appendChild(gridItem);
  }
}

// Handle the grid item click
function handleItemClick(e) {
  const item = e.currentTarget;
  const image = item.querySelector('img');

  if (item.classList.contains('matched') || image.style.display === 'block') {
    return;
  }

  image.style.display = 'block';

  if (firstSelected === null) {
    firstSelected = item;
  } else {
    const firstImage = firstSelected.querySelector('img');
    if (firstSelected.dataset.pairId === item.dataset.pairId) {
      firstSelected.classList.add('matched');
      item.classList.add('matched');
      score += 1;
      scoreElement.textContent = score;
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        firstImage.style.display = 'none';
        image.style.display = 'none';
      }, 1000);
    }
    firstSelected = null;
  }
}

createGrid();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.game-container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 50px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.grid-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.score-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

````html
The HTML ```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Image Pair Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="game-container">
    <div class="score-container">
      <p>Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="grid-container">
      <!-- The 10x10 grid will be generated here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
````

I've specified the dimensions: `const gridSize = 10 * 10;`
and I'm iterating through the 'for' loop, but it's all new to me and I'm not very confident that I haven't introduced a problem.

```
// Create the grid
function createGrid() {
  const imagePairs = createImagePairs();
  const shuffledPairs = shuffle(imagePairs);

  for (let i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    const gridItem = document.createElement('div');
    gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
    gridItem.dataset.pairId = shuffledPairs[i].substring(0, shuffledPairs[i].length - 1);

    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = `images/${shuffledPairs[i]}.jpg`;
    gridItem.appendChild(image);

    gridItem.addEventListener('click', handleItemClick);

    gridItems.push(gridItem);
    gridContainer.appendChild(gridItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example, the squares render in a `10x10` pattern.